# Pass variables from LoginController to Views - Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

I have recently been using Laravel,
I hope to explain myself well. I use the standard authentication that Laravel offers, I need to invite two variables from the controller which would be **$title** and **$desc** to the template.

The problem is that by opening the **auth/loginController** controller there is no function where to insert these variables.

How can I do?

Comment: From loginController to views ? what do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Login Controller there is AuthenticatesUsers trait where all methods are implemented. You can extend them in your controller and pass any variables that you want

[image]

For example, you can extend `public function showLoginForm()` method and insert into its body any variables that you need.

Comment: For the "Forgot your password?" Instead how do I proceed?